# How to remove border when there is no text

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML:

```
<ul class="uSPStyle">
    <li><a class="tfSPHT clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tfSPHT1" href="javascript:void(0);"></a></li>
    <li><a class="tfSPOPT clickMe" title="" data-toggle=".tfSPOPT1" href="javascript:void(0);">Here we go</a></li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sikni8/oqcaz326/

How can I modify the JQuery so, when the link is blank, it should remove the `border-bottom` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the border is on the parent list item, just add `.parent()` to what you have:

```
$('.uSPStyle li a').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';
}).parent().hide();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/oqcaz326/1/)**